# How to change 'background-position' based on width of browser/screen

Tags: jquery, css, resize, background-position

I have created a simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve. Please take a look

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bg-left">
<div class="content">
        Some content here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   display: block;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.bg-left {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/hDheuGJ.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.content {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gnPC6/

**This code contains:**

1) DIV of 100% width which contains a background image positioned top left (i.e. black triangle)

2) Within this div there is another div which is, e.g. 960px wide and centred. Some content will be placed here.

**Problem:** If the width of the browser window is resized , the black triangle will still be visible in the top left and the result is that this image obscures the foreground content.

**What I'm trying to achieve is thus:**

1) If the users browser is resized to 1050px or below, then the BACKGROUND-POSITION of the black triangle will adjust such that the more the browser is resized, the less visible the black triangle is (i.e. the background image dynamically slides off the screen to the left)...

If users window is 1051px or above, background position should remain as 0px 0px;

If users window is 1050px, background-position should be 0px -1px;

If users window is 1049px, background-position should be 0px -2px;

If users window is 1048px, background-position should be 0px -3px;
etc.

This is in essence what I'm trying to achieve, but I cannot figure out where to start with Javascript to solve this.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, many thanks!

**EDIT** I am aware of media queries but I don't believe they can solve this problem effectively. I don't want to just change CSS based on the width of the browser, I want the background-position to change dynamically as the browser is resized. For this I'm sure a javscript solution is required, rather than hundreds of @media declarations

Comment: What you want to do can be done using CSS media queries. Go read-up.

Comment: As above, media-queries will solve this easily. Some links to help you for the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries , http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: Thanks but I already read up on media queries. As far as I know, I can specify something like `@media (max-width: 1050px) {.bg-left { background-position: 0px -1px }}` but how do I do this so that the background position is dynamically altered as the width decreases pixel-by-pixel?

Comment: Yes, media queries *could* be used to do this, but it would be highly inefficient to do so.  Note that the OP wants to shift the bg image over by 1px for potentially hundreds of breakpoints.  It would be more efficient to restructure the code so that the image doesn't have to be shifted at all (or it repositions itself without the aid of media queries).

Comment: In practical terms the requirement is pointless. The only viewers who re-size their browsers too such a degree are developers. The OP should concentrate on MQ for design breaking points not pixel perfect issues.

Comment: Thanks @cinnamon, that's what I was thinking. With media queries I would have to specify the background-position for over 100 min-width's. I was hoping there would be some jquery/javascript that can achieve this

Comment: @Paulie_D I have simplified my problem in order to get a simple, flexible answer. It's not about resizing a browser to a specific degree, its about supporting potentially any browser width without the background image obscuring the content

Comment: you sure you need jquery? i made some fiddeling and removing fixed widths and adding some padding to de .bg container, made it: http://jsfiddle.net/gnPC6/11/

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Your javascript looks promising but doesn't seem to work on the Fiddle. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ghilton if you are worried about supporting potentially any browser width.. use media queries like others have suggested to target specific device widths, and then you will cover all your bases, instead of trying to incrementally change things on every pixel change. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ -

Comment: @ghilton I only changed CSS so the margin of the bg width is kind of respected; you should try to fix styling issues with CSS as long as you can

Comment: I gave a js solution that I adapted from a script from a site of mine that needed to adjust the bg similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (using jquery):
http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/gnPC6/18/

Obviously, you'll need to stretch the browser to see it in the correct dimensions.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function debouncer(func) 
{   
    var timeoutID, timeout = 100;
    return function () 
    {
        var scope = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function () 
        {
            func.apply(scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(args));
        }, timeout);
    };
}

$(window).resize(debouncer(function () 
{
    bgResize($(document));

}));

     function bgResize(){

    var thisWidth = $(document).width(),
        offSet = thisWidth - 1051;

    if(offSet < 0) {
        $('.bg-left').css({'background-position': offSet+'px 0px'});   
    }     
}    

$( document ).ready(bgResize);

</script>
```

The timeout/debouncer is to keep the script from firing at every pixel the browser moves, and instead limiting it to a tenth of a second before firing. If you don't care about creating possibly hundreds of function calls in one go, you can just do:

```
   $(window).resize(bgResize);

     function bgResize(){

    var thisWidth = $(document).width(),
        offSet = thisWidth - 1051;

    if(offSet < 0) {
        $('.bg-left').css({'background-position': offSet+'px 0px'});   
    }     
}    

$( document ).ready(bgResize);
```

Comment: Hi @spacebean, apologies as I have not tested your solution. I was creating a HTML demo for a project at work but I have been pulled into something else. Can't wait to test it out though and I will let you know as soon as I do. Your work has not gone to waste!

Comment: I am currently testing this code. I like your style, for the most part it works however the only issue is that it does not change the background-position until the user resizes the browser. So this does not work if a user loads the webpage with their browser already resized. Any idea how to apply the CSS change on load? Many thanks

Comment: Also - your code adjusts the background-position in the y direction, but I am trying to adjust it in the x direction

Comment: Hmm, including the `$( document ).ready( bgResize($(document)) );` should mean it automatically loads. Does it not work for you when you view the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry you're right. it works in the fiddle but not when I extract the solution for my HTML demo. I am storing the JS in a separate file, could this be why?

Comment: I updated the code above, it makes more sense anyway (no need to pass in the window, see the bgResize function) and that should work now. I'm actually not sure why it DOES work on jsfiddle without being wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks - this works now. One more question - it is a bit slow to respond to changes in browser width, is it possible to make this a smoother process? I changed the timeout to 1 and it seems to be more smooth now but I just wanted to check with you if this was a good idea or not, i.e. did you set Timeout=100 for a reason? Thanks!

Comment: It's set to a tenth of a second in order to prevent hundreds of calls to the same function. You can set it to more/less as you want or remove it all together. If there are other js elements in the page it can end up causing issues though without the slight delay. You can add a console log in the bgResize function to see how often it is called when you do a resize. I edited my answer above with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've found your breakpoint where the overlap occurs, you could use something like this to cover the narrower browser viewports:

http://jsfiddle.net/gnPC6/21/

```
.container {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.content:before {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/hDheuGJ.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The EASIEST way is by using this small amount of jQuery I use mainly to resize fonts based on the window size. It works perfectly every time...

1. check the window width
2. create a var for width
3. change the css based on a fraction of the overall width

You can easily modify the code from my fiddle to change the css of your background position. You can also add as many lines of css as needed to change other css elements as well:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
function checkWidth() {
var windowSize = $(window).width();
$('#num').css( "font-size", windowSize / 4 );
```

etc in the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/insitemobile/xhP8k